# Hudson. Compilation failure: cannot access EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring, maven, hudson

I have some problem with me project.
Hudson output me next result:

```
 [ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
D:\integration build notifier\workspace\notifier\sms-notifier\src\main\java\com\century\remote\notice\SMSServlet.java:[46,45] error: cannot access EnvironmentCapable
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
```

//--------------------------

```
[DEBUG]
Trace org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
C:\ttt\ttt\.hudson\jobs\integration build notifier\workspace\notifier\sms-notifier   \src\main\java\com\century\remote\notice\SMSServlet.java:[46,45] error: cannot access EnvironmentCapable
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    C:\tts\ttC\.hudson\jobs\integration build notifier\workspace\notifier\notifier\main\java\com\century\remote\notice\SMSServlet.java:[46,45] 

  error: cannot access EnvironmentCapable
```

Project BUILDs SUCCESSFUL on my computer, but it isn't compiled on the Hudson.

I don't understand a reason of my bug.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using spring framework?